# EditorFor issue with datetime datatype

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My model looks like this

```
public class Movie
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Movie Name")]
    public string NewsFull { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Release Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "dd/mm/yy")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

in edit view i am using

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
```

but i am not getting the existing date for selected movie, rather it displays 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM,
i have checked in the database the existing date is 1/9/2001

i tried chrome n mozilla both but same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this attribute too

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
```

and check if it works when you change the date format to something like below

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Comment: after playing with it little bit, i removed DataType(DataType.Date)] and it worked for me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your DataFormatString to "{0:dd/MM/yy}" and ApplyFormatInEditMode to true:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}")]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx